# Calculating values of the chords

Tags: soft-question

If we have a semicircle of diameter AB (with length 1) and center O, then we can find the approximate value of the chord AC, by the following formula,where $x$ represents the value of the angle AOC

$\sqrt\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[90]\frac{10{\pi}}{\sqrt{50}×4}^{(2x-90)}×\left(\frac{90}{x}-1\right)×\sqrt{ 2}+1\right)^2+1}$

For example if the value of $x=60$, we will get 0.4999469..
So , my formila gives an approximate value of the chord.
There is formula similar to mine, in the literature?

Comment: You can find the exact value through some trigonometry.

Comment: $|AC| = 2r\sin(\frac x2)$. But wow, that's some function you've got there :O How in world did you come up with that?

Comment: In any case, your formula just looks like something that maybe happens to aproximate the real answer on some range. Unless you can say something surprising about it, I don't think it's significant at all.

Comment: If there were anything like this in the literature, I imagine it would have a greatly-simplified form; for instance: 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(1+\dfrac{90-x}{x}\cdot\dfrac{\pi^{(x-45)/45}}{2^{(x-60)/30}}\right)^2}}$$ 
Or, perhaps better, defining $t := x/90$,
$$\frac1{\sqrt{1+\left(1+\dfrac{1-t}{t}\cdot\dfrac{\pi^{2t-1}}{2^{3t-2}}\right)^2}}$$